# Script for render many different material on one object

Tags: rendering, scripting

I am new in Blender and i have only small experiences in scripting. But I would like to ask somebody for one thing. I have one object a would like to render it with many different external pictures like a surface of the object and every render save separately. I have no idea how can the sript look like. Some idea?
Thanks
Honza
[image]

Comment: Do you just want to change the color of the material, or a completely different material?

Comment: Hallo, thank you for your reply. I made material with the asigned picture in this array. Texture Coordinate->Mapping->**Image Texture**->Diffuse BSDF->Material Output. And in the section **Image Texture** need to change image automaticly and save each like separate rendered file like png.

Answer (score 3):

If your "image" is actually an Image Sequence then it will cycle through the various images as the frames of the animation iterate.  Your screenshot shows you using a single image.  If you were instead to load that texture node with multiple files (shift-click, or maybe just <kbd>a</kbd> in the file selector dialog) then it would have a few more options.

[image]

*Edit:* The example image is for 4 frames, but it is not hard to build an image sequence of thousands of frames if they are all in one directory (<kbd>a</kbd> selects them all).  If they are in multiple directories you might have to use some python to get them all into the same image sequence, but I haven't experimented with that situation.

If you were unable to use an image sequence, you would probably end up using a bunch of MixRGB nodes and keyframe the `factor` value to switch between inputs.  This would quickly get messy as the number of options grows and your binary tree of MixRGB nodes becomes a forest.

Comment: Hallo **Mutant Bob**, thank you for your reply. But I dont think, that this can solved my problem. I have cca 100 (maybe more) pictures i need to change and set every one like a key frame is for a long time. Or I am wrong?

Comment: This example doesn't use keyframes, an image sequence is a series of images named with a numerical sequence, in this example a different image wil be used each frame, so you just render an animation of 100 frames to use all 100 images.

Comment: Thank you both **@MutantBob** and **@sambler**, you were right. Finaly it doesn´t work like I would like, but in this time it is more then enough. The rest have to come with more experiences.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way I could find. it saves all the image in the folder defined by the folder variable. Remember that you need to put the **\** instead of ****.

Hope you'll understand the code.

```
import bpy


obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.active # Active Object

mat_names = ["Material.001", "Material", "Material.002"] # names of the materials

mats = []

folder = "C:\\test\\test" # folder to save the different images in: Remember the double bar (\\)!

bf_area_type = bpy.context.area.type

for m in mat_names:

    mats.extend([bpy.data.materials[m]]) #adding the materials based on their names

for i, mat in enumerate(mats):

    #if the object has not material slot, it adds one slot to it.
    if obj.data.materials:

        obj.data.materials[0] = mat
    else:
        obj.data.materials.append(mat)

    #render
    bpy.ops.render.render()

    #change the area type to Image editor
    bpy.context.area.type = "IMAGE_EDITOR"

    #Save the image
    bpy.ops.image.save_as(save_as_render=True, copy=True, filepath=folder+"//Render{}.png".format(i), relative_path=False, show_multiview=False, use_multiview=False)

    #Reset the area type
    bpy.context.area.type = bf_area_type
```

Comment: Hallo Fabrizio, thank you for your reply. I tried to run the script with correct \ for windows . But Blender wrote that something wrong in line 16. `mats.extend([bpy.data.materials[m]])` # adding the materials based on their names. Some idea?

Comment: can you wrote the complete error code? maybe you haven't some materials named Material.001, Material and Material.002